# bootstrap select doesn't work properly in dropdown-menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a bootstrap select select picker, in a normal HTML dropdown. I had many issues, the select picker was not closing after I chose an element, I fixed that with this code:

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (target.parents('.bootstrap-select').length && target.is("a")) { //CHECKING IF TARGET IS 'a' BECAUSE WANT THIS METHOD TO ONLY EFFECT THE DROPDOWN IN MY DROPDOWN-MENU
        //console.log(target.parents('.bootstrap-select').children(":first"))
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.bootstrap-select.open').removeClass('open');
    }
});
```

I still have many problems with the select picker. Why is this happening? I am guessing it is because the selectpicker is in a dropdown-menu.

- I cannot close the picker when I click on it
- When I type words in search, every letter replaces the previous one, I can only type one letter. data-live-search does not work properly

How can I make sure a bootsrap select work properly in a dropdown-menu?